# Why is there no "lange" function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

This question is simple, I hope its not stupid.

When I am making loops in python, I always find myself doing the following:

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    foo(i)
```

In python, we have lots of cool functions that do wonders for iteration such as `zip` and `enumerate` but why dont we have a built-in function that returns a range from an iterable? Such as:

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in lange(my_list):
    foo(i)
```

This function could be easily defined as follows, but I really dont understand why there's no such a built-in.

```py
def lange(seq):
    return range(len(seq))
```

Edit:

To give more background information on why, often I need to take some irregular slices from a list and the best is to use a function and pass the index and the list, such as:

```py
def crazy_slice(my_list, i):
    if i - 5 > -1 and i + 5 < len(list):
        return [my_list[i + x] for x in (-5, -2, 0, 2, 5)]

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    foo(crazy_slice(my_list, i))
```

Comment: There aren't many situations where you want the indices but not also the values from a sequence. So `enumerate` is the right thing to use.

Comment: Woah, that was closed fast, I think I'll never understand why I keep asking questions here, I'm sorry guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always more pythonic to loop through array values and avoid manipulating indexes.   If you do need the indexes, you'll probably also need the values so you should use enumerate.

Or, you could use enumerate to get only the indexes (note that this is more syntax candy than efficient code):

```
for i,_ in enumerate(my_list):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because loops over `range(len(someseq))` are not Pythonic in the first place; making it easier to write them isn't useful. 99.99% of the time, they're written by people coming from a C-like background, who use them inappropriately when direct iteration, `zip`, `enumerate`, or an `itertools` helper function would accomplish the job both more clearly (including useful names) than anonymous index values, more efficiently, and more generally (working with arbitrary iterable inputs, not just sequences).

In  short, shaving half a dozen characters off "The Wrong Solution™" is not a benefit.

Comment: Side-note: I know of one scenario where iterating over a `range` of indices makes sense, when you need to iterate over slices of a sequence (where it's possible to do without `range`, but it's fairly ugly and not at all obvious unless you grok Python pretty deeply). Aside from that, it just doesn't come up much in *good* code. Supporting rare cases by bloating the built-ins isn't worth it, when `range(len(x))` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

range(len(seq)) is already short enough, there is no need to create a whole new function to do this. Also, adding new functions may cause namespace collisions.

Additionally, I don't think StackOverflow is the right site to ask this question.